# How much damage will my Snowball do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want a good, cheap way to kill blazes. I have noticed that snowballs are relatively effective but how much damage does it do to a blaze? I want to make a piston crusher to leave the blaze to be a one hit to a snowball.

Answer (score 8):

Snowballs deal 3 ([image][image]) health points of damage to blazes.

It is also worth noting that snowballs don't damage mobs except for Blazes and Ender Dragons.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Snowball)

Comment: Snowballs no longer damage ender dragons.